# Folder to be found using %folder-name%

Tags: windows, command-line

As we can go to the temp folder by typing %temp% in the run Window.Is there any way to make this command work for our folders as well

eg-If we have a folder say SUPER then i want this folder to open when i give %SUPER% in the run window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%temp%` is referencing an environment variable.

These are defined in `Control Panel / System / Advanced / Environment Variables` for XP and in Windows 7 you can just search for "environment" in the start menu and choose `Edit Environment Variables`.

Add the variable name you want in the name field, without the percentage signs.  Add the folder you want to open in the value field.

If this is just for a user, then apply it at the user level, or use system if it is for all users.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

To set the variable `%SUPER%`, just execute this command:

```
set SUPER=C:\foo\bar\SUPER
```

To set this variable automatically each time you open a terminal, go to

```
Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables...
```

and create a user variable (for your account) or a system variable (for all accounts) with name `SUPER` and value `C:\foo\bar\SUPER`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Actually you need to create a new enviroment variable for your folder then you can access it quickly using your trick.

Let's say for C:\USER\SUPER:

1. Right click on My Computer > Properties > Advance System Settings > Advance tab > Environment Variables...
2. Add your new variable, you can choose the name whatever you want, the value should be your full path of the folder. This case: SUPER and C:\USER\SUPER
3. Access it by typing %SUPER%

This works on my Windows 7, not sure on other versions.